# Defining class level Authorizers using Authorize ruby gem with Rolify/Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So after putting the following at the top of my Product Controller:

```
  authorize_actions_for(Product)
```

...and this to the top of my Product.rb:

```
  resourcify
  include Authority::Abilities
```

...and this to the top of my User.rb

```
  rolify
  include Authority::UserAbilities
```

I was able to have this rule obeyed from application_authorizer.rb:

```
def self.default(adjective, user)
  user.has_role? :admin
end
```

In other words only admin users could engage with Products in any way.

However, when I created a product_authorizer.rb like the following

```
class ProductAuthorizer < ApplicationAuthorizer
  def self.creatable_by?(user)
    user.has_role? :admin
  end

  def self.updatable_by?(user)
    user.has_role? :admin
  end

  def self.deletable_by?(user)
    user.has_role? :admin
  end
end
```

I was not seeing the rules obeyed. I was seeing that my non-admin user **still couldn't** access the show action for a product. Shouldn't this be allowed given the above?

I tried adding this to Product.rb:

```
self.authorizer_name = 'StyleAuthorizer'
```

I also tried commenting out the main rule in app_app.rb

```
#def self.default(adjective, user)
# user.has_role? :admin
#end
```

...but still no glory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very most basic `default` in [Authority's source code](https://github.com/nathanl/authority/blob/master/lib/authority/authorizer.rb#L20) always returns false. So unless you explicitly authorize non-admins in a `self.readable` method, they won't be able to access show pages.

Remove the other methods you have in your `product_authorizer.rb` file (they're not necessary) 
and replace them with

```
def self.readable_by?(user)
  true
end
```